# Junit tests in SpringBoot app are failing when using CommanLineRunner interface

Tags: java, spring-boot

There is a SpringBoot application, with SomeService and test class to test this service.

I can run my tests and everything works fine but as soon as I use `CommandLineRunner` interface ("*`implements CommandLineRunnner`*") in my main application class `MyApplication` then all my tests are starting to fail.

The problem is when I'm trying to get argument parameter in `run` method, like **`args[0]`** then my tests are starting to fail.

and I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:774)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:755)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:319)
```

any idea how to fix it and run my tests without getting this error ?

my code looks like this:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication implements CommandLineRunner  {

    @Autowired
    SomeService someService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        String file = args[0];
        someService.calculate(file);
    }

}

@Component
public class SomeService {


    // some methods here...
}

@SpringBootTest
public class SomeServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService;

    @Test
    public void some_test() {
        someService.someFunction();
        //....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `CommandLineRunner#run()` will be executed after spring boot start up . The input parameter `args` at here is normally passed from the command line that is used to run the spring boot app.

When you execute `@SpringBootTest` , it by default will have the empty argument list but now your method accesses its 0-index item by `args[0]` which will cause `IndexOutOfBoundsException` happens which in turn causes `SpringApplication#callRunner()` throws `IllegalStateException`

Suggest you to make your `CommandLineRunner#run()` to be null safe something like :

```java
@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {  
       if(args.length >= 1) {
            String file = args[0];
            someService.calculate(file);
       }
}
```

Or configure that argument list by :

```java
@SpringBootTest(args= {"foo","bar","baz"})
public class FooTest {

}
```